# How do I use multiple repositories for a single entity in Doctrine2?

Tags: doctrine-orm, repository, entity

I'm considering using Doctrine2 in a project for the first time. In my research, one thing that alarmed me is this:

```
<?php
/**
 * @Entity(repositoryClass="BugRepository")
 * @Table(name="bugs")
 **/
class Bug
{
    //...
}
```

It appears I can only associate one Repository with each entity? What would I do if this Repository class grows too large (too many methods/code) and I would like to separate it into multiple Repository classes?

Comment: You would move your logic into one or more service classes and then inject the repository.  Repositories are mostly focused on queries.  Most of the real work should be done elsewhere.

Comment: yeah, but I've got a lot of queries

Comment: So you are saying there is no way to do this in Doctrine2? Your only recommendation is to slim up the repository, nothing else we can do? I have considered perhaps some "factory" in that the repository could some how lazy-load off other repositories, but everything comes through a single repository (the doctrine one assigned) to be built.

Comment: Play around a bit.  I'll think you will find several approaches.  Yes the repository could act as a factory to spin off queries.  Or you just create specific query classes and inject the repository into them.

Comment: gotcha @Cerad. If you want to give an answer with the example of injecting the doctrine repository into a query class, I'll accept that answer. But otherwise, thanks for the guidance!

Comment: I'd suggest not using doctrine and use something better, Rails, MySQL ANYTHING else. Doctrine is crap from what I've experienced.

Answer (score 2):

For exactly your situation there is **Repository as a Service**:

```
<?php

/**
 * @Entity
 * @Table(name="bugs")
 **/
class Bug
{
    //...
}
```

Then create first repository:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

final class FirstBugRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Bug::class);
    }

    // ... some methods
}
```

And next one:

```
<?php

use Doctrine\ORM\EntityManager;
use Doctrine\ORM\EntityRepository;

final class SecondBugRepository
{
    /**
     * @var EntityRepository
     */
    private $repository;

    public function __construct(EntityManager $entityManager)
    {
        $this->repository = $entityManager->getRepository(Bug::class);
    }

    // ... other methods
}
```

Do you want to know more and a full example? Check post [How to use Repository with Doctrine as Service in Symfony](https://www.tomasvotruba.cz/blog/2017/10/16/how-to-use-repository-with-doctrine-as-service-in-symfony/)